# Styles based on touch capabilities rather than viewport media queries?

Tags: css, touch, media-queries

**tl;dr:** Does it make sense to scope "mobile" CSS under a `.touch` class (added by Modernizr) rather than with media queries based on viewport size?

I am creating mobile styles for a site designed to be desktop-only (i.e. the page is fixed at ~900px wide, many targets are too small for touch, etc). The site has *lots* of forms, some tables, and no images/video/charts. I cannot control the HTML structure (except with JS, which I'd like to avoid), and I cannot make meaningful changes to the existing desktop styles.

I've written a new style sheet that overrides those styles where necessary to make it work well on a phone and on a tablet in portrait mode using `max-width` media queries.

The problem is that when you turn the tablet to landscape mode the screen becomes 1024px wide which is where desktop styles ought to take over. However, a tablet is still a touch device and I feel the "mobile" style is better suited to tablets (larger tap targets, nicer layout of the form fields and labels, off-canvas menu, etc). It seems quite clunky and disorienting for a site to suddenly change just because you rotated the device.

Should I scope the mobile styles under the `.touch` class added by Modernizr instead of the viewport width? On the surface it doesn't sound like a bad idea, but then again I know that viewport-based media queries are the proper way to write styles so I can't help but feel I will run into trouble down the line.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Modernizr to pick between two stylesheets to load.

In a file called small-enough.css or something, import your mobile styles based on a media query for tablet portrait size and down. Documentation found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import). Just have this one line in it.

```
    @import path/your-mobile-styles.css @media (max-width: [tablet portrait width]);
```

Then with modernizr if it's a touch device just load the mobile styles. If it is not touch load the file that uses the media query to decide to load the mobile styles.

```
    Modernizr.load({
      test: Modernizr.touch,
      yep : 'your-mobile-styles.css',
      nope: 'small-enough.css'
    });
```

Comment: I tried that (I'd like to avoid loading all mobile CSS/JS on desktop browsers) but there was too much FOUC since the desktop CSS/JS loads first. I'll have to see if I can also use Modernizr for the desktop CSS, then load either one but never both.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably target those devices using a media query along the lines of

```
@media only screen and and (min-device-width:~whatever~) and (max-device-width:1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  styles
}
```

We should also remember that not all mobile devices are touch enabled, such as some Blackberry phones, so enabling some features/styling based on the .touch class that modernizr adds can also help.

Comment: What about tablets wider than `(max-device-width:1024px)` ?

Comment: The same syntax would apply, for example   `@media (max-device-width: 1280px) and (orientation: landscape) {}`

A handy resource can be found at http://nmsdvid.com/snippets/

Comment: What I meant is AFAIK that most modern desktop browsers also support that media query (e.g. both `max-device-width` and `orientation`). So a desktop monitor that's 1024px or 1280px would get those styles, but I want to leave the desktop alone.

Comment: Take a look at http://cssmediaqueries.com/ and it'll help you tailor your queries for what you need. You can also find useful information at http://www.mydevice.io/ You could also try using `media="handheld"` in the link to your style sheet.